# SQL Query needed for desired Output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the sample data which gets filled into sql server database from different PLC machine. datetime,machineID, cycletime(TIME TAKEN TO PRODUCE THAT MATERIAL) AND shift

[image]

There are 3 shifts in company A(6:30Am to 2:30PM), B(2:30 to 10:30), C(10:30 to 6:30AM).
when i take C Shift count, my query should take next day data also till 6:30AM time. Where as A shift should take current day data starting from 6:30Am to 2:30Pm.Where as B shift should take current day data starting from 2:31pm to 10:30PM.

Desired Output::

[image]

I need to find the quantity for each hour...6:30 to 7:30 what is the quantity... 7:30 to 8:30 what is the quantity and so on for each individual hour. Quantity should not get added with previous hour quantity.. individual hour quantity

Comment: Is 6:30 to 7:30 required or can we sum value from 6:00 to 7:00 and so on?

Comment: Please share your existing sql.  I also notice end/start times of 2:30/2:31.  Does this pattern also extend to 10:30:00/10:30:01 and 6:30:00/6:30:01 ?? or is it 6:29:59/6:30:00 ??

Comment: In the Desired Output, is the Hour column the beginning or the ending of the hour?

Comment: you should provide sample data in textual form to get many answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this, and then wrap it with

```
"SELECT ... just the columns you want
 FROM this example
 GROUP BY ...."

SELECT 
      -- isolate Date from Time from HourMinutes  only for testing
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [MDate], 111) as RealDate
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MTime], 108)  as RealTime
      ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MTime], 108),4,5) as HrMn

      -- from midnight to 6:30 adjust to prior day
      , Case When (CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MTime], 108) < '06:30:00') 
            Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day,-1,[MDate]), 111)
            Else CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [MDate], 111)
         End as RptDate

      -- from after the half hour, report it with the next hour
      ,Case When (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MTime], 108),1,5)) > '23:30:00'
            Then  ' 0:30' 
            When (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MTime], 108),4,5)) > '30:00'
            Then  STR(DATEPART ( hour , [MTime] ) + 1, 2)  + ':30' 
            Else  STR(DATEPART ( hour , [MTime] ), 2) + ':30'
         End as RptHour

      ,[MachinelD]
      ,[CYCLETIM]
      ,[Shift]
  FROM [StackOver].[dbo].[CShift]
```

For your add-on question of getting only Previous or Current shift, 
we need to think ahead to what the Where clause might look like--

```
Where (MDate = @fromDate and MTime >= @fromTime)
Or    (MDate > @fromDate)
```

And then,  before the main SELECT/FROM,  create appropriate local vars --

```
Declare @fromDate as datetime, @fromTime as datetime

If      CONVERT (time, GETDATE()) <= '06:30:00'   Begin
    Set @fromDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))  --yesterday
    Set @fromTime='14:30'
    End
Else If CONVERT (time, GETDATE()) <= '14:30:00'   Begin
    Set @fromDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))  --yesterday
    Set @fromTime='22:30'
    End
Else If CONVERT (time, GETDATE()) <= '22:30:00'   Begin
    Set @fromDate=CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) --today
    Set @fromTime='06:30'
    End
Else   Begin  -- time > 22:30
    Set @fromDate=CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) --today
    Set @fromTime='14:30'
        End
-- for testing only, show the values        
Select @fromDate, @fromTime
```

I leave any remaining question(s) to your own solution

Comment: Thanks..Its working. One more question how to get  Only Previous shift and current Shift rows alone from this query all the time